Abelianizer and Van Kampen pushout as a presentation
Is there a general way to write the abelianization of a group and a pushout of fundamental groups as in Van Kampen as a presentation $\langle X|R\rangle$ for $X$ a subset of a group and $R$ a set of relations?

I think presentation is the term you want.

You cannot guarantee that in your presentation generators will be elements of the group. You should also edit your question to improve clarity.

Regarding the abelianization, you should first assume your group $G$ is already given by a presentation with generators and relators, in the form $$G=\langle X | R \rangle
$$
To get a presentation for the abelianization you just have to add some relators saying that each pair of generators commutes:
$$ab(G) = \langle X | R, [x,y] \rangle
$$
where $x,y$ vary over $X$ and $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$.
Regarding Van Kampen's Theorem, where $X=U \cup V$, you should first assume that you have:

Presentations for $\pi_1(U)$ and $\pi_1(V)$ already given in the forms
$$\pi_1(U)=\langle X|R \rangle \quad\text{and}\quad \pi_1(V) = \langle Y| S \rangle
$$
(with $X,Y$ disjoint),
generators for $\pi_1(U \cap V)$ are already given, in the form of a generating subset $Z \subset \pi_1(U \cap V)$
for each $z \in Z$, words given of the form $w_U(z)$ in the letters of $X$ and $w_V(z)$ in the letters of $Y$, which represent $z \in U \cap V$ included into $\pi_1(U)$ and $\pi_1(V)$ respectively.

Once you have all of that, your presentation for $\pi_1(X)$ is given by
$$\pi_1(X) = \langle X,Y \mid R, S, w_U(z)^{-1} w_V(z) \rangle
$$
where $z$ varies over $Z$
